# System does not work anymore after migrating to UEFI

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, bios, uefi

I have recently updated my BIOS to UEFI (big mistake...). When I boot in Windows 7 x64 now, it does not recognize any USB driver (even mouse and keyboard).I tried to use Windows Repair Disc to Restore but nothing worked. I am about to re-install Windows 7... But I have applications, importan applciations that I don't want to lose.

Is there any other way to solve this problem without re-installing Windows 7?

Thanks a lot to anybody will help me!

Edit:

My hardware is:

- Motherboard: GIGABYTE GA-Z68MA-D2H-B3 (rev 1.0)
- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits

Since the "Windows" directory is not listed in Windows Backup, I thought that I will not end-up with the same system. (see here @Karan)

[image]

This is my Device Manager:

[image]

Comment: More information about the specific hardware is required to help you.

Comment: See in my edit, I hope that is enough for you... If it is not, tell me what information do you need, and I will provide you everything.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the drivers for the motherboard? You may need to find a old [PS/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_connector) style mouse and keyboard to be able to try this out.

Comment: I have already put a PS2 mouse and Windows recognizes it. But I don't have the utility software to install all the drivers. Although, I installed some drivers from http://www.gigabyte.com.ro/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3855&dl=1#driver. My computer still doesn't recognize no USB device.

Comment: If there is no other method of repairing it, I would be intersted in how can I backup my application (all the software in C:) and if the Windows Backup will be able to backup the software...

Comment: Doing a system image backup with Windows 7, Clonezilla or whatever won't help since you'll end up with the same broken OS when you restore. And there's no other way to backup just your apps.

Comment: @Victor - What firmware revision are you using for this board?

Comment: revision 1.0 for my motherboard

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your device manager?

Comment: @Victor - Have you tried to update the firmware on your motherboard?  Why don't you just switch back or turn on legacy mode?

Comment: I cannot switch back to my legacy BIOS. Or do you know any method of doing that?

Comment: @JMK, see in my edit, the Device Manager.